# How do I interact with a serial port using the ESCape key in python?

Tags: python-3.x, keyboard, pyserial

I am trying to use the ESCape key to go back to the Menu page and I can’t seem to implement it into an if statement. Once the ESCape key is pressed it should 
return to the main menu. I am using Python 3.7

```
import serial
import Keyboard
ser = serial.Serial ('COM18', baudrate = 115200, timeout = 1) #USB Serial Device

def getMenuData():
    PhoenixMainMenu = ser.readline().decode('ascii')
    return PhoenixMainMenu   

def printScreen():
    n=20
    while n <= 20: #as long as 
        print(getMenuData()) 
        n-=1 
        if n >= 0: 
            print (getMenuData())
            n-=1 
        else:
            break     

while True:
    print (printScreen())
    print ('Escape Key brings you back to main menu')
    UserInput = input('To access option type its coresponding number: ')
    if UserInput == '1':
        ser.write(b'1') #HW test
        print ('first is the worst')
        secondInput = input('To access the function type letter: ')
        if secondInput == 'a':
            ser.write(b'a') 
        else:   
            print ('Invalid entry. Please Try again.')
        break

    elif UserInput == keyboard.wait('esc')
        ser.write(b'0x1b') 
        print ('Main MEnu')
        print (printScreen())        
        break

    else:
        print ('Invalid entry. Please Try again.')
```